# Dovecot's Sieve filter creates duplicate of incoming email

Tags: dovecot, sieve

I'm using Dovecot with Sieve filters.

I've got a default filter: `sieve_before = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve.d/default.sieve`

And after that some user's filter: `sieve_dir = ~/sieve`

Problem: Dovecot filters "default.sieve" with original incoming message but user's filter filters with duplicate of message. So if I want to move incoming message to another folder - it works but original of the message stays in INBOX.
Solution is simply I believe but I can't figure it out.

User's filter contains:

```
fileinto "Folder";
```

Log:

```
...: stored mail into mailbox 'INBOX'
...: stored mail into mailbox 'Folder'
```

`if duplicate` is false

Here is the content of `sieve_before` filter:

```
require ["fileinto", "imap4flags"];
if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "YES" {
setflag "\\Seen";
fileinto "Spam";
stop;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Change this:

```
require ["fileinto", "imap4flags"];
if header :contains "From" "something" {
    fileinto "Folder";
    addflag "\\Seen";
stop;
}
```

By this:

```
require ["fileinto", "imap4flags"];
if header :contains "From" "something" {
    fileinto "Folder";
    stop;
}
```